When building a layer of a neural network in TensorFlow, is there a way to specify a parameter for each individual neuron in the layer?
I'm trying to build a simple 3-layer neural network using TensorFlow. My hidden layer has two unique requirements for which I'm building my own Layer class:

I need a unique function that is applied to the whole layer.
Each neuron has a specific parameter (which will not be trained) that is unique to that neuron and used inside my function.

My question is about the second requirement: if I have a list of size, say, 50, and I want to have each of my 50 neurons use 1 number for that list, how do I do so?
import tensorflow as tf
import math

class RBF_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(RBF_layer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel", shape = [int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs], 
                                      initializer = 'ones', trainable=False)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        r = tf.norm(tf.math.subtract(inputs, param))
        return 1/(4 * math.pi * r)

I'm very much a beginner in anything related to neural networks and tensorflow. I'll post the layer I'm trying to build to help give you the general gist of what I'm attempting. What I'm trying to do is have 'param' change with each individual input to the corresponding parameter. Thanks in advance.
